# Double column format with a specific class file

Tags: two-column

Here comes a sample LaTex code:

```
\pdfoutput=1

\documentclass{ws-ijbc}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 Abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Test}

This is a test section


\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\caption{This is a test table.}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrr}
  \hline
  $\epsilon$ & $N^{*}$ & $a$ & $b$ \\
  \hline
  0.0001 & 23 & $N^{*} + 3$ & 9.65 \\
  0.1 & 17 & $N^{*} + 2$ & 6.59 \\
  0.6 & 14 & $N^{*} + 2$ & 5.14 \\
  0.9 & 12 & $N^{*}    $ & 2.54 \\
  0.99 &  8 & $N^{*}    $ & 1.59 \\
  0.999 &  6 & $N^{*} + 1$ & 2.04 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\resizebox{\hsize}{!}{\includegraphics{test.jpg}}
\caption{This is a test caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where the specific .cls file and the figure can be found here:

http://www.worldscientific.com/page/ijbc/submission-guidelines

My question: What is the best and most efficient way to obtain a double-column document using the specific class file?

Many thanks in advance and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Please, add an official source for the class; nobody is going to download a zip file from an untrusted source (not thay you are untrusted, but mediafire is). Anyway, if you're using a class issued by WorldScientific for submissions, why should you use double column format if the class doesn't use it?

Comment: @egreg How can I provide the class file more safely? WorldScientific provides a class file which corresponds to single column, however the published paper is formed in double column and they do not share the double column class file.

Comment: Do you intend to publish your document in WorldScientific?

Comment: @samcarter I have already published a paper in WorldScientific. However they do not release the special class file which they use to obtain the final published document in double-column. So, I want to find a way to obtain it using the regular single-column class file.

Comment: If it is for publication: use whatever template they provide, do not modify it and they will do the final layout (which is not necessarily done in latex)

Comment: @samcarter But I want to be able to reproduce the final published document whenever I want. So I must obtain the modified template for double-columns.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just put `\twocolumn` in the preamble.